# Is there any difference between the two ways to dump an object to a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

Method 1:

```
json.dump(object, file('object.json', 'w'))
```

Method 2:

```
f = file('object.json', 'w')
json.dump(object, f)
f.close()
```

I often use method 2 to dump object to json files, but it looks so ugly. Method 1 looks good and clear, but I feel confused whether it is right to open a file object as the parameter, who will take control of that object after the object has been stored in the JSON file?

Answer (score 2):

> I feel confused whether it is right to open a file object as the parameter, who will take control of that object after the object has been stored in the json file ?

No one takes control; the `file` you created in the `json.dump` call from method 1 leaves scope after that line and is therefore implicitly closed. Both methods are therefore equivalent.

If you want to be more verbose, I'd suggest to use a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement):

```
with file('object.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(object, f)
```

This ensures that the file is always closed properly at the end of the block, even before control is passed to any exception handlers if an error occured.

Comment: True true, but what about explicit being better than implicit? :P

Answer (score 1):

I would say there is not *that* much difference but that the second method could be considered better from a readability standpoint; [Readability counts.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

In your example, the filename and mode that you are using to open the file are hardcoded strings. If they were both variable names (as they most likely would be in a real world example), I feel that method #1 would be a little harder to parse while reading.

One more observation would be that using method #1, you wouldn't be able to continue writing to that file object as you have no variable referencing it; You would need to reopen it in order to append more data.

Answer (score 1):

they are the same internally, you can check the source code.